# Extract Json property from RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I want to extract Json property from Raven DB database. I am extracting it from Ravendb studio from index as below. In below query, parameter `Body` is of type `json` and I want to extract its one field (let's say field1) from it. How can it be done?

```
from index 'Selectdata' as message 
order by message.ProcessedAt desc 
select {
    UniqueMessageId: message.UniqueMessageId,
    MessageId: message.MessageMetadata.MessageId,
    MessageType: message.Headers["EnclosedMessageTypes"],
    TimeSent: message.Headers["TimeSent"],
    ProcessingStarted: message.Headers["ProcessingStarted"],
    ProcessingEnded: message.Headers["ProcessingEnded"],
    ProcessingEndpoint: message.Headers["ProcessingEndpoint"],
    ProcessedAt : message.ProcessedAt,
    Body:message.MessageMetadata.Body //json body
}
```

Comment: Why don't you index that field (field1) in a static index, so that you can query on it ?

Comment: @Danielle - How can I make index on property of  document parameter (Body)?

Comment: Can you extract this field (the one you are interested in) from the json body and place it as a property in your entity class? If yes, then you can index it.

Comment: @Danielle - No, as I am not able to parse to Json body.

Comment: Try using ```Search()``` which will perform full-text search on the 'Body' field property. See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/Csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-search. 
Note: First enable the full-text-search capability on the 'Body' field in the index definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Full-Text-Search** on the 'Body' field.
See code examples in the [RavenDB Demo](https://demo.ravendb.net/):

**Full Text Search with Static Index - Single Field**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-with-static-index-single-field

**Full Text Search with Static Index - Multiple Fields**
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/text-search/fts-with-static-index-multiple-fields

And also can use the `Search()` method on 'Body' field property. See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/Csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-use-search

Comment: Can we query on two indexes with some joining condition? I have to select field in json Body as well as other properties of other index.

Comment: Maybe the way to go for that is to define one index of type: **'Multi-Map-Index'**. You define one index that indexes data from more than one collection.
So you can index a property from one collection and from another collection in one index, and then of course you can query this index.

See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/studio/database/indexes/create-multi-map-index and https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/indexes/multi-map-indexes